# How do Decompress image using BASE64 in android studio

Tags: java, android

I created `String` from `ByteMap`

```
 public String StringImage(Bitmap bitmap) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

    byte[] imageByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    String encodeImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

    return encodeImage;
}
```

and I placed this on sql server.

Downloading this from sql server is not a problem. After download I want to create `ByteMap` from this string. It means I need decode that string and create `BitMap`, but that is too hard for me.

Here I am trying decode string and create bitmap

```
String donwloadImage = jsonObject.getString("image");
String encode = Base64.encodeToString(donwloadImage.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
byte [] bytes = Base64.decode(encode, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap  bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert Base64 String to Bitmap like this -

```
 byte[] decodeByte = Base64.decode(encodeImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
 Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeByte, 0, decodeByte.length);
```